# Rod cutting - recursive

Tags: c++, c, recursion

Question: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/

My code at: http://ideone.com/HGXk3t

I tried solving for recursive problem but getting unexpected result.
For rod cutting problem, **I am taking max of two calls of the same recursive function: One using that index and another without using price at that index.**
But the answer is not what it should be.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

// A utility function to get the maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a : b;}

/* Returns the best obtainable price for a rod of length n and
   price[] as prices of different pieces */
int cutRod(int price[], int n, int i)
{
    if(n<1 || i==0)
        return 0;

    return max(price[i-1] + cutRod(price,n-(i+1),i), cutRod(price,n,i-1));
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {17, 17, 1};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("Maximum Obtainable Value is %d\n", cutRod(arr, size, size));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use std:: vector, std::max. Don't use stdio.h and limits.h.

Comment: @Rahul--  pick a language; C and C++ are not the same.

Comment: @manni66-- posted code is C. I see no need for `limits.h` here, but why shouldn't `stdio.h`  be used? After all, it is needed for `printf()`.

Comment: `limits.h` is not needed unless you're using `INT_MIN` as your negative weight for the algorithm.

Comment: I removed limits.h. I was previously using INT_MIN, but removed that later.

Comment: @DavidBowling the question is tagged C++ so any C++-centric advice is on topic until the tag is removed. Not using stdio.h means not using any associated facilities like printf either.

Comment: @Rahul If you think either of the two answers were helpful, consider accepting one.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive call is losing information during its descent/ascent.

During your return call, seeing as it's working backwards in the array, all it will do is return the max possible value and ignore remaining chucks.

Assume this extreme example where `n=2;` and `p=[100,1];`. Ideally, the answer is 200.

On the first call, the return value is `return max(1,cutRod(2,2-1));`.
The second parameter of the first call `cutRod(2,2-1)` ignores the 2nd chuck of the rod and begins to examine the 1st chuck of the rod on the recursive call.

The second level of the call gives `max(100,cutRod(2,1-1));`

And the third call, `i=0`, so it `cutRod(2,0) = 0`.

Examining the levels of our recursive calls, we only take the max of the pair of values:

```
level 3 = 0 //0 comes from cutRod(2,1-1)
level 2 = max(100,0) //100 comes from cutRod(2,2-1): 0 comes from cutRod(2,1-1)
level 1 = max(1,100) //1 comes from p[2-1]: 100 comes from max(100,0)
```

So 100 ends up being the max value and not 200 on your return call

```
return max(price[i-1] + cutRod(price,n-(i+1),i), cutRod(price,n,i-1));
```

I would not recommend this way of multiple recursive calls to solves this dynamic-programming problem. Instead, here is the example found in 
*Introduction to Algorithms*,
third edition Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein pg.363

```
#include <limits.h>
//p is the price array
//n is the initial size of the array or 'rod'
int cutRod(int p[],int n){
  if(n == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  int q = INT_MIN;
  for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    q = max(q,p[i-1]+cutRod(p,n-i));
  }
  return q;
}
```

**Recursive solution w/o for loop** *requires analysis

```
//p is the price array, n is the size of the array/rod, i is index initial called with 0
int cutRod(int p[],int n,int i){
  if(n<=0 || i>=n){
    return 0;
  }
  return max(p[i]+cutRod(p,n-(i+1),0),cutRod(p,n,i+1));
}
```

Comment: yeah, I know this is a DP problem. But first I wanted to solve using recursion and then use that approach for DP. But I got stuck here in the recursion itself.
I have doubt in the FOR loop which is being used. Why cant we solve it like KNAPSACK problem?

Comment: @Rahul With the knapsack problem, you have variables that behaves as discrete objects. Once you put something into the sack, you can't put it back in since it's already in the sack, so you have "unique" subproblems during the recursive iterations. With cutRod, moving the index of price array does not work. You have to start from 0 for each sub-iteration of a rod or else information is lost. See my edit for a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

The rod cut problem basically states that given a rod that we can cut into discrete increments, and prices for those discrete sizes of rod, how do we cut the rod such that we get the best price for it as a whole. In your example, you pass your function an array of size 3 {17, 17, 1} which, given our problem statement, says that a piece of rod of size 1 is work 17 units, a piece of size 2 is worth 17 units, and piece of size 3 is worth 1 unit. Obviously, the optimal solution to your example would be to cut the rod into single units and sell it. The example in the link you provided has a price list like this: {1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20}. The solution for this is less obvious and requires a more nuanced approach to solve it. This type of situation is one where the recursive solution shows it's value.

Your solution seems to attempt to solve the naive recursive version of this problem, where we do not consider things like overlapping sub-problems discussed in the link you provided. To solve this the naive way, you examine all of the sub-problems and return their max results, then combine them to find the global maximum. For instance, for a rod of size 8, you need to find the maximum prices returned for a rod of size 7, 6, 5... and combine those options to find a global maximum. Your solution doesn't find and combine those options, which is why you are not getting hte correct result. The most intuitive way to examine and combine all sub-problems for this problem is to do something like this pseudocode:

```
def cutRod(arr price[], int n)
   if(n <= 0)
     return 0;
   int max_val = -inf //set maximum value to negative infinity
   for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
     max_val = max(max_val, price[i] + cutRod(price, n-i-1));
   return max_val;
```

This is basically the code given as the naive example in your link provided. What it does is loop over all of the possible price options for a given size of rod an sum the value returned by selling said size of rod for its given price, and the maximum price possible for the rest of the rod. For their example {1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20}, the code would first find the max price for a rod cut at position 1, so you add price[0] with cutRod(price, 7). This finds the maximum price you can sell a rod of size 7 for, which is 18 (17 and 1), and adds price[0] to that, returning 19. This process continues, until you find the maximum value for all of the subproblems, which ends up being 22.

As you can see, in this example we examine basically every possible reasonable option for our rod cut scenario, where as in your code above, you examine only some options, many of which don't actually sell the entire rod.

Note that this solution is far from the most efficient possible solution for this problem. It does not account for overlapping subproblems, which is addressed in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

#Python solution
it will give TLE error, so make sure to use memorized solution.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ans=0
    def cutRod(self, price, n):
        l=[]
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            l.append(i)
        rod_l=n
        self.solve(l,price,n,rod_l)
        return self.ans
    
    def solve(self,l,price,n,rod_l):
        if n==0 or rod_l<1:
            return 0
        if l[n-1]<=rod_l:
            self.ans=max(self.solve(l,price,n-1,rod_l),price[n-1]+self.solve(l,price,n,rod_l-l[n-1]))
            return self.ans
        else:
            self.ans=self.solve(l,price,n-1,rod_l)
            return self.ans
```